# c++ initialize other class in constructor

Tags: c++, list, constructor, initialization

Ok, so there's something I can't understand with the c++ constructor:

If I use the initializer list method, the code works:

```
Client::Client() : id(), name(){
    // this works!
}
```

But the regular method doesn't:

```
Client::Client(){
    id = String();
    name = String();
    // does not work
}
```

String is just another class I wrote; The String default constructor is as follows:

```
String::String(){
    str = NULL;
}
```

Afaik, initializer lists allow you to initialize consts and references, but I dont really see how it helps here?

What am I missing?

EDIT: declarations:

```
class String {
    char *str;
public:
    String();
    String & operator =(const String &rhs);
}

class Client {
    String id, name;    
public:
    Client();   
};
```

String does have an assignment operator but I want to use it to copy the contents of "str" into the lhs String, could this be the problem? as in it tries to use my assignment operator and fails?

SOLVED:

Ok, It is indeed the assignment operator, it seems that if I give it a String with str = NULL, it fails to strcpy and stops the program. Sorry for not being accurate, I did try to debug and found out it failed @ the constructor of client when I try to initialize the String vars as I have more code coming after that. So I understand that the 1st method of initialization works **because it just straight up does not use the assignment operator.**

```
String & String::operator =(const String &rhs){
    /*if(!rhs.str){ return *this; }*/ // had to add this line!
    str = new char[strlen(rhs.str)];
    strcpy(str, rhs.str);
    return *this;
}
```

Thank you guys a bunch.

Thanks ahead,
Michael.

Comment: Please provide the declaration of `class Client` and also `class String`.

Comment: Does `String` have an assignment operator?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it give unexpected output? Does it not compile? Expand your code a bit to a mcve.

Comment: I have added the header for the classes.
Does not work as in stops running abruptly, does not prints output after these parts run.

Comment: What is the definition of the assignment operator? Does it deal with `NULL`? What doesn't work about the code?

Comment: `stops running abruptly` at which line does it stop? Didn't you try to debug?

Comment: You need to add the code ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that reproduces your "stops running abruptly" when we run it. Otherwise we can only guess. As it stands now, your code compiles correctly (after adding definition to the constructor and ass. operator) but doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, It is indeed the assignment operator, it seems that if I give it a String with str = NULL, it fails to strcpy and stops the program.
Sorry for not being accurate, I did try to debug and found out it failed @ the constructor of client when I try to initialize the String vars as I have more code coming after that.

So I understand that the 1st method of initialization works because it just straight up does not use the assignment operator, is that correct?

Thank you guys a bunch.

Comment: Yes, the 1st method uses initialization, the 2nd one uses default-initialization + assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> it fails to strcpy and stops the program

Well, there's your bug. In the line `id = String();` you call the copy assignment with a `String` with null `str` member as the parameter. Your copy assignment operator apparently tries to `strcpy` from the null pointer which has undefined behaviour.

Best advice that I can give you is "use `std::string`".

> So I understand that the 1st method of initialization works because it just straight up does not use the assignment operator, is that correct?

Correct. Both versions default construct the members first, but the second one does copy assignment as well. You don't need to have a user defined constructor at all for `Client` if default initialization is sufficient.

Comment: That is correct, I need to get used to c++ and its nuances as it gets tricky sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelPapkov I recommend getting used to `std::string`. It has much fewer caveats than character pointers and will save you many headaches.

Comment: Well creating your own String is this case in part of an assignment that's why I did it :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these two constructor implementations is that the former explicitly default-constructs the elements, whereas the second does so implicitly, then calls the assignment operator on a default-constructed instance.

```
Client::Client() : id(), name(){
}

Client::Client(){
    id = String();
    name = String();
}
```

If your assignment operator is broken, then the first version will work and the second won't.

You should always prefer to initialize in the initialization-list to doing so in the constructor body, as the latter will result in an unnecessary construction, then an assignment.